# Running an NSTimer for objects in an NSArray

Tags: ios, objective-c, timer, nsarray, nstimer

I have an `NSArray` of `NSObjects`. For each object in the `NSArray`, I'd like to run a timer until it finishes, then restart it for the next object.

The objects in the `NSArray` will be used to populate `UITextField`s.

I've tried `for (NSObject *myThing in self.ArrayOfMyThings)`, it ends up displaying one timer correctly on screen while instantiating a bunch of others. Thank you for reading. I welcome suggestions on how I might go about accomplishing this feat of software engineering ;)

My timer is instantiated in this method:

```
- (IBAction)startButton:(UIButton *)sender {
    if (self.isPaused == YES) {
        NSLog(@"startButton pressed");
        self.timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0
                                                      target:[NSBlockOperation blockOperationWithBlock:^{
                [self counting];
        }]
                                                    selector:@selector(main)
                                                    userInfo:nil
                                                     repeats:YES];
        self.isPaused = NO;

    }
}
```

The timer counts using this method:

```
- (void)counting {
    // ** If the timer is RUNNING **
    if (self.isPaused == NO && secondsRemaining > 0) {
        secondsRemaining-=1;
        elapsedTime+=1;
        self.timerLabel.text = [self timeFormatted:secondsRemaining];
        NSLog(@"counting: isPaused = %@", self.isPaused ? @"YES" : @"NO" );

        if (secondsRemaining < 4 && secondsRemaining > 0) {
            [self voiceCountdownAlert];
        }
    // ** If the timer is FINISHED **
    } else if (self.isPaused == NO && secondsRemaining == 0) {
        [self resetTimer];
        [self voiceTimerCompleteAlert];
        secondsRemaining = elapsedTime;
        elapsedTime = 0;
        self.timerLabel.text = [self timeFormatted:secondsRemaining];
        NSLog(@"counting: The timer was reset");
    // ** If the timer is paused **
    } else if (self.isPaused == YES) {
        NSLog(@"counting: isPaused = %@", self.isPaused ? @"YES" : @"NO" );
    }
}
```

This method is how I stop the timer manually:

```
- (IBAction)stopButton:(UIButton *)sender {
    NSLog(@"stopButton pressed");
    [self.timer invalidate];
    self.timer = nil;
    self.isPaused = YES;
}
```

Comment: Where is the for loop?

Comment: I took it out because I couldn't get it to work. The value for the timer gets fed into `count` in the `secondsRemaining` integer.

Comment: But the problem you describe involves a loop and then you show different code. So what's the problem with the code you show?

Comment: @AdrianB, actually i am not getting you what you want. can you please describe thoroughly .

Comment: @Rob I think I follow what you're saying. So at the top of the implementation I'd have `@property (nonatomic, strong) NSIndex *myIndex`, then set the index in the completion block of the `NSTimer`, & increment the index in the `counting` method?

Comment: As an aside, you can simplify the creation of your timer, e.g. `[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(counting) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest creating a class property to keep track of the numeric index of the "current" item, e.g.:

```
@property (nonatomic) NSInteger currentIndex;
```

Use this to identify which item in the array you are currently using. When you start, initialize this to 0. Then, in the "timer is finished" routine, just increment your index, make sure you're not at the end of the array. If you're done, then `invalidate` your timer. If not, just carry on with the new index value.

Comment: That did the trick! My code will look like a Rube Goldberg project, but it works! Thank you so much for the suggestion! Hopefully as my programming skills advance, I'll be able to shrink it down.